# Rapid way to prove $ [e_{ij},e_{lk}]=\delta_{jl}e_{ik}-\delta_{ki}e_{lj} $

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $e_{ij}$ denote the $n\times n$ matrix with entries all zero but the $(i,j)$th one, in which we put $1$.

Let then $\delta_{ij}$ be the Kronecker Delta.

Finally $[A,B]:=AB-BA$ is the commutator ($A,B\in M_n(\Bbb C)$).

Does exist a rapid way to prove that
$$
[e_{ij},e_{lk}]=\delta_{jl}e_{ik}-\delta_{ki}e_{lj}\;\;?
$$

Comment: You mean more rapid than writing down a definition of matrix multiplication?

Comment: @mixedmath: Yeah.

Answer (score 2):

Let the matrix be denoted by $E$, and the $i,j$ entry by $E_{i,j}$. Then we can write:

$$E_{i,j}=\delta_{i,j}$$

If $A$, $B$ are two matrices, the elements of the product are denoted by

$$(AB)_{i,j}=A_{i,j}B_{i,j}$$

If you write these two down definitions, it seems to come out quite quickly.

Comment: This is exactly what I would do, the only problem being the amount of indices that must be used. Using latin + greek indices and different sets of letters may be enough though ($n,m,l$ or $i,j,k$ or $a,b,c$, etc.).

Comment: Good point. I think if you can choose a consistent convention, and maybe use superscripts for the matrices and subscripts for the entries, it can be done reasonably.